# Ninject Auto Instantiate singleton instance

Tags: c#, ninject

All,

I have a Ninject module that binds a singleton class. How in Ninject can you have it auto create the single instance of that class without it being injected anywhere.

The class in question has a thread that needs to spin up when the app starts.

I bind the class like this:

```
Bind<IPollingService>().To<DefaultPollingService>();
```

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Can't you just call `kernel.Get<IPollingService>()` in a background thread directly after you're done registering your bindings?

Comment: kernel.Get<IPollingService>() is how I've achieved this.